# Show an iframe, hiding origin request

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, cors

I have 2 web servers. Server A with public access, and server B, that has limited access, only from Server A.

I want to show content from server B inside an iframe (or div) in server A, but I want the server, not the client, to get the data.

My question is - how do I handle client side scripts received from server B ? should I send it to the client and try to handle AJAX on server A ? is it even possible ?

Comment: actually, it's like what VPN and anonymizers do - but how they they handle javascript and AJAX ?

Comment: What platform are you using? S3, heroku, etc. Does each server have it's own domain?

Comment: @zer00ne - S3 it is, same domain, different subdomain. why should it matter ?

Comment: I've never had time to set something like this myself, but I was thinking this might be possible: https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/OTIzODkzXzM5MDM0NjA

Comment: I didn't quite get the figure...

Comment: The box in the middle is a bucket that "translates" to the left box and communicates with the right box via CORS. Your question may be too broad if this concept needs detailed explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121457/discussion-between-nati-and-zer00ne).